# collection view arrays tied to index

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, populate, collectionview

Im making a three view controller project with the first two views are collectionViews. The selected cell will load second view controller with segue and another array depending on which index was selected on first main view. Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to tie a data to load in the second collection view.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet private weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!


var collectionData = ["cell1", "cell2", "cell3", "cell4", "cell5", "cell6", "cell7", "cell8"]



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let height = (view.frame.size.width / 2.76)
    let width = view.frame.size.width / 1
    let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as!
        UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: width, height: height)


        }

    }

    extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return collectionData.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath)
    if let label = cell.viewWithTag(100) as? UILabel {
        label.text = collectionData[indexPath.row]

        }
    return cell
    }

    didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "BannerSegue" {
       if let _ = segue.destination as? BannerSelection, let _ = sender as? IndexPath {

      }
    }
  }
}
```

that is the main view controller. then it has a segue to this view

```
import UIKit

class BannerSelection: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var collection2: UICollectionView!

    var BannerData = ["bannerA1", "bannerA2", "bannerA3", "bannerA4", "bannerA5", "bannerA6", "bannerA7", "bannerA8", "bannerA9", "bannerA10", "bannerA11", "bannerA12"]

    var selection: String!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let height = (view.frame.size.width / 3.76)
    let width = view.frame.size.width / 1
    let layout = collection2.collectionViewLayout as!
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: width, height: height)

    }

}

    extension BannerSelection: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return BannerData.count
}

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let bannercell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "BannerSelectionCell", for: indexPath)
    if let label = bannercell.viewWithTag(1) as? UILabel {
        label.text = BannerData[indexPath.row]
    }
    return bannercell
}
    func collectionView(_ BannerSelection: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    }
}
```

So what im trying to achieve is let's say... index 2 to have an array of "bannerB1, bannerB2" so on and so forth. then i will apply the same technique for the second view controller to populate the final view with a end UIImage. Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

You can store the data of the first view in the UserDefaults and then retrieve the first vc's data from the second view and load them

Answer (score 0):

As your data Structure is unclear to me, Seems like your data is a dictionary of array like that

```
dict =    [
       "cell1" : [Banner1, Banner2,..]
       "cell2" : [Apple1, Apple2, ..]

       //so on 

    ]
```

What is the structure of your data structure, let it to be saved in UserDefaults.

```
UserDefaults.standard.setValue(dict, forKey: "myDataStructure")
```

while retrieve in second view controller

```
let array = dict["cell1"] as? Array<String> // depends on the data structure
```

and populate your viewController.